# selecting the item to edit AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

My problem is I expected to get the element clicked getting selected for edit,I am in fact getting the `addExpert view` but my element is not already selected considering that I have `data-ng-model="Item.genre` and `data-ng-model="Item.rate` on my 2. select what do I miss? 
[here s the complete](https://plnkr.co/edit/FRi9Go3nZMzusG247qdK?p=preview)

**experience view --**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="txtName">Company Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="search" data-ng-model="search"  class="form-control" />
</div>

   <table class="table  table-hover">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Genre</th>
     <th>Rating</th>
   </tr>
  <tr  data-ng-repeat="item in message | filter:search" data-ng-click="editItem($experience)">
    <td>{{ item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{ item.genre}}</td>
    <td>{{ item.rate}}</td>
  </tr>

   </tbody>

  </table>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="addExperience()">
    add experience
  </button>
```

**addexpertView**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="chcTech">Tech</label>
  <select name="chcTech" id="chcTech" class="form-control" data-ng-model="Item.genre">
    <option value="c#">c#</option>
    ...
  </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="chcRate">Rate</label>
  <select name="chcRate" id="chcRate" class="form-control" data-ng-model="Item.rate">
    <option value="1">1</option>
  ....
  </select>
....  
  </div>
```

**edit controller**

```
 cvApp.controller("editExperienceController",["$scope", "$location", "$routeParams","experienceService",
    function($scope, $location, $routeParams, experienceService){

  $scope.Item= experienceService.getExperience()[parseInt($routeParams.FOO)];
      $scope.save=function(){
        //save
        $location.path("/about");
      }
       $scope.cancel=function(){
        $location.path("/about");
      }
    }])
```

**config of the routeProvider**

```
cvApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider

      ....
        .when('/about/:FOO', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/addExpert.html',
        controller: 'editExperienceController'
      })
      ...
       .otherwise({
        redirectTo:"pages/home"
      });
    });
```

**getExperience function in a service**

```
cvApp.factory("experienceService", ["$rootScope", function($rootScope) {
      var svc = {};

      var message = [
      ....  
       {
          name: "Azure",
          genre: ".net",
          rate: "4"
        }];

        svc.getExperience=function(){
          return message;
        };
       ....

    }]);
```

Comment: " am in fact getting the `addExpert view` but my element is not already selected" Could you please elaborate on your problem statement?

Comment: Do you have array of genre and rate type?

Comment: i would like to get the element clicked already selected in my addexpert.html instead nothing is selected

Comment: the data are defined in the service  "experienceService" you have a variable called message with genre and rate is that ypu mean jerry?

Comment: i mean from where you bind your select box?

Comment: what $routeParams.FOO contains.

Answer (score 0):

in the experience view it's not $experience but $index

```
<tr  data-ng-repeat="item in message | filter:search" data-ng-click="editItem($index)">
```